# Encoding a string

Tags: python, encoding

How does encoding work of a string? Thanks.

Comment: a, b, c are just representation of digits, nothing to do with real characters. Read it as a base 4: "21231", and so thing will be more obvious. I do not think you can represent `d`, OTOH we do not know which character represent the 0 digit.

Comment: I'd expect this sentence is part of a larger paragraph or article that explains the concept in more depth…?!

Comment: No: base 4 has digits from 0 to 3. (base 10 has 0 to 9). If you put 4, the value will spill into the previous digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can a string made up of a,b,c,d be converted using **base4**

In this case a,b,c,d are digits, traditionally 0...9 are used for system with base <= 10, but other characters might be used. For example say you might write binary number using `-` and `+`.

Note that various base systems are working same way, but are just using subsequent powers of different number. Consider `21231` in base-10 system, it is:

```
2 * 10 ** 4 + 1 * 10 ** 3 + 2 * 10 ** 2 + 3 * 10 ** 1 + 1 * 10 ** 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This could mean  b = 2, a = 1, c = 3, and babca = 21231 in base4.